# How to import data from csv file and paste to ppt table using pptx?

Tags: python, python-pptx

I am trying to import data from a csv file and loaded to ppt table using pptx.
The number of columns are fixed but the number of rows can be varies depends on the condition.
The number of rows can be up to hundreds.

Is there a easy way to create table in ppt using pptx in Python?

Sample data:

```
Name   Contract No.   Start_Date  Total   Delivered   Ready
A         220104      2022-02-03    10       5          2
B         220104      2022-02-03     5       3          2
C         220104      2022-02-03    13       12         3
D         220104      2022-02-03    12       3          4
E         220104      2022-02-03    15       8          3
...        ....          ....       ..       ..         ..
...        ....          ....       ..       ..         ..
...        ....          ....       ..       ..         ..
```

Here is the code I've got so far.

```
template = prs.slide_layouts[2]
slide.prs.slides.add_slide(template)
path_order_tbl = os.path.join(path_data, f'df.csv')
if os.path.exists(path_order_tbl):
    df_order = pd.read_csv(path_order_tbl)
    x, y, cx, cy = Inches(2), Inches(2), Inches(4), Inches(1.5)
    shape.slide.shapes.add_table(6,20,x,x,cx,cy)
    table = shape.table
```

Comment: Can't you just open the csv in excel and copy paste that into pwp?

Comment: I want to do it in python since I want to make automation code.

Comment: My md2pptx and mdpre open source projects - between them - can make slides from CSV, including setting column widths and alignments.. md2pptx uses python-pptx to do the slide creation. Might save you some trouble.